# How to separate out and save html files which are merged in a single file

Tags: javascript, html, file

I have few html files each of them have 8-10 html pages merged inside them. All these are separated by the name of the page/file followed by <!DOCTYPE html... tag.

How can I separate out these individual page/file and save them with their respective names?

Comment: Can't you just do this by hand?

Comment: @Konowy, actually there are 100s of such files.

Comment: It would be easier if you gave an example of this file. Maybe on pastebin.

Comment: Not sure if I did correctly. I pasted the HTML contents here https://pastebin.com/10ahGC0Q Please see that it has 2 HTMLs inside. I need is to separate out these 2 and save as 2 different HTML files. Preferably want the file name as per the string mentioned in the main HTML before the <!DOCTYPE tag.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote nodejs program to fix your problem:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const fileName = process.argv.slice(-1)[0]
const file = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf-8')

let fileRest = file

const htmlEndTag = '</html>'

while (true) {
  const end = fileRest.indexOf(htmlEndTag)
  if (end === -1) {
    break
  }
  const oneFile = fileRest.slice(0, end + htmlEndTag.length)
  const match = oneFile.match(/\(([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\)/)
  const name = match[1]
  const content = oneFile.slice(match[0].length + match.index)

  fileRest = fileRest.slice(oneFile.length)
  fs.writeFile(name + '.html', content, () => {
    console.log('Done writing', name)
  })
}
```